# Unsilent skype chat

Tags: windows, skype

i have a group chat in skype with four people. Somehow i happend that the chat became silent. By silent i mean that when skype i closed to the system tray and someone says something in the chat, the orange dot does not appear in the tray to notify me of a new chat message.

I already tried to leave the chat and get attached again, but the chat remains silent. If other people chat to me i get notified normally.

What can i do to enable notifications for this group chat again.

I use skype 5.9 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the chat and from the main menu Conversation -> Notification settings -> Notify me...

Comment: If this solved your own problem, you can accept the answer, which will highlight it as a solution to your problem for others